# Is it safe to create a regression test that relies on running out of file descriptor limit?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors, testing

I'm writing a regression test for my modification of Nmap and I'm wondering if it's a good idea to create a test that would basically perform a large-scale connect() scan on 127.0.0.1/8, which would fail if the scanner is implemented poorly so that I would know once I've fixed this bug.

Is this a bad idea to deliberately run out of open file descriptors to test this behavior? Does this kind of test affect other users or parent processes?